# how do you put a period right next to a variable in python?

Tags: python

im  new to python so this will be really easy for you guys i'm sure.

i wrote a simple thing in python, but i was curious how to put a period next to the variable i am using, i will show you here:

```
i = 5
print "i is equal to", i,"."
```

i run it and it comes out like this:

```
i is equal to 5 .
```

how do you make it so the (period) is right next to the 5, like "i is equal to 5."

i tried searching for this but i feel like it too simple i can't find it lol and i don't know what things are called exactly, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
print "i is equal to %d." % i
```

As of Python 2.6, strings have a [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function that can alternatively be used:

```
>>> print "i is equal to {}".format(i)
i is equal to 5
```

It's useful if you have a placeholder that's used multiple times in the format string:

```
>>> print "i={0}, a.k.a. 'i is equal to {0}.'".format(i)
i=5, a.k.a. 'i is equal to 5.'
```

Comment: awesome thank you i didnt know they had that, cool, ill accept this answer after 11 mins

Comment: I would suggest to use the new format string function, instead of the old string formatter

Answer (score 7):

You can also concatenate like this,

```
print "i is equal to " + str(i) + "."
```

Comment: If you might ever need to do i18n for an app, you'll find that `.format()` is a much better idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "i is equal to", str(i) + "."
```

You can also just use the str() function at the very end, no need to convert everything to strings. Easier when you have more variables and text in the print line.

Example:

```
print (a,"+",b,"is equal to", str(a+b) + ".")
```

vs

```
print (str(a)+" + "+str(b)+" is equal to "+str(i)+".")
```